# PHP NORMALLY wont call this method but with xdebug is CALLED

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug, ubuntu-16.04

I'm on XAMPP 7.0.13-1 (PHP 7.0.9) on Ubuntu. I've installed Xdebug 2.5.0 and currently use it with NetBeans 8.5.

**I have this situation:** When I run the following code debugging, the final value of `dump` is `NombreOApellidoValidoNombreOApellidoValidoContraseñaValidaEmailValido` (expected). BUT when I run it under the same input data without debugging it, I get `NombreOApellidoValidoNombreOApellidoValidoContraseñaValida` (unexpected):

```
public function __construct($nombres, $apellidos, $contraseña, $repContraseña, $email, IUsuarioDB $capaDatos){
$this->dump = "";
$this->capaDatos = $capaDatos;

$this->valido = $this->NombreOApellidoValido($nombres, 'nombresValido');
$this->valido = $this->valido && $this->NombreOApellidoValido($apellidos, 'apellidosValido');
$this->valido = $this->valido && $this->ContraseñaValida($contraseña, $repContraseña);
$this->valido = $this->valido && $this->EmailValido($email);

$this->nombres = $nombres;
$this->apellidos = $apellidos;
$this->contraseña = $contraseña;
$this->email = $email;

echo $this->dump; 
if($this->valido){
    $this->codigoActivacion = md5(time());
    $this->capaDatos->GuardarUsuario($this);
}
```

}

```
public function NombreOApellidoValido($nombres, $aValidar){
    $this->dump .= "NombreOApellidoValido";
    //Do stuff
}

public function ContraseñaValida($contraseña, $repContraseña){
    $this->dump .= "ContraseñaValida";
    //Do stuff
}

public function EmailValido($email){
    $this->dump .= "EmailValido";
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $this->emailValido = true;
        if($this->capaDatos->EmailUnico($email)){
            $this->emailUnico = true;
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->emailUnico = false;
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        $this->emailValido = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening. The input is the same in both scenarios, the only difference is that in one I debug and in the I don't. Judging by the output, PHP isn't executing `EmailValido($email)` when it runs normally.

Comment: Make sure the code in the first code block `public function __construct($nombres, $apellidos...` is correct. The pasted code has a typo, note the extra ' that makes half the code red as it thinks it's a string.

Comment: I seem to have type that by mistake when writing the question. I corrected it. The source is correct.

Comment: Then use Xdebug to step through the code and see where the two executions diverge (variable values, method calls, etc)

Comment: When i do that the program works just exactly as i would expect. But when i don't it doesn't. Funny thing

Answer (score 0):

1. Your methods like `NombreOApellidoValido` must return `true` or `false`, now they are returning nothing, means `NULL`.
2. Look at the [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in PHP. Try to conclude expressions in right of equal sign in brackets like this:

   `$this->valido = ($this->NombreOApellidoValido($nombres, 'nombresValido'));
   $this->valido = ($this->valido && $this->NombreOApellidoValido($apellidos, 'apellidosValido'));`

Comment: The methods do return something those values in the actual code. Also, I just tried what you say about the bracket, however it doesn't solve the problem, but thank you.